# Arduino Anti-Theft System

Tags: arduino, system

I have an arduino anti-theft sistem.
The problem is the function void disarm()

```
//define Variables
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <RTClib.h> 
//LCD
#define I2C_ADDR    0x27
#define LCD_COLUMNS 20
#define LCD_LINES   4
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(I2C_ADDR, LCD_COLUMNS, LCD_LINES);
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
// Definire PINI
const int ledPin4 = 4;
const int ledPin5 = 5;
int lastButtonstate = LOW;
int lastState;
int button = 3;
// PIR
int pir = 2;               // choose the input pin (for PIR sensor)
int pirState = LOW;             // we start, assuming no motion detected
int val = 0;  
//Senzor dist
#define trigerPin 9
#define echoPin 10
long duration, distance;
// Arm/Disarm
bool isArmed = false;
//tastatura si parola
char password[5] ="1234"; //create a password
int pozisyon = 0; //keypad position
const byte rows = 4; //number of the keypad's rows and columns
const byte cols = 4;

char keyMap [rows] [cols] = { //define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypad

  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins [rows] = {14, 15, 16, 17}; //pins of the keypad
byte colPins [cols] = {18, 19, 20, 21};

Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keyMap), rowPins, colPins, rows, cols);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin();
  pinMode(trigerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);
  //Setup for LEDs
  pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin5, OUTPUT);
  // Pin Mode Buton
  lastState = digitalRead(button); 
  //Setup for LCD
   lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(5,0);
  lcd.print(" Sistem ");
  lcd.setCursor(2,1);
  lcd.print(" anti-efractie ");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {
    int currState = digitalRead(button);
    if(currState != lastState && currState == HIGH) {
        if(!isArmed) {
            arm();
        }
        else if(isArmed) {
            disarm();
        }
    }
    lastState = currState;
    pirsenzor();
    distsenzor();
    delay(100);
}
//=================================FUNCTII & SENZORI=================================


void arm() {
  if(!isArmed) {
    // Armare si cerere parola
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Armare sistem");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Introduceti codul:");
    delay(50);
    int attempts = 0;
    do {
      char whichKey = myKeypad.getKey();
      if (whichKey != NO_KEY) {
        lcd.setCursor(pozisyon, 1);
        lcd.print("*");
        password[pozisyon] = whichKey;
        pozisyon++;
      }
      if (pozisyon == 4) {
        // Verificare parola corecta
        if(strcmp(password, "1234") == 0) {
          digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin5, LOW);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin5, LOW);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin5, HIGH);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin5, LOW);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
          lcd.print("Sistem armat");
          delay(3000);
          lcd.clear();
          isArmed = true;
          break;
        } 
        else {
          // Verificare parola incorecta
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
          lcd.print("Parola Incorecta!");
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();
          pozisyon = 0;
          attempts++;
          if(attempts == 1)
          {
             lcd.clear();
             break;
          }
          continue;
        }
      } 
      
    } while (!isArmed);
 }
}

void disarm() {
  if(isArmed) {
    // Dezarmare si cerere parola
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Dezarmare sistem");
    Serial.println("Sunt aici");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Introduceti codul:");
    delay(50);
    int attempts = 0;
    do {
      char whichKey = myKeypad.getKey();
      if (whichKey != NO_KEY) {
        lcd.setCursor(pozisyon, 1);
        lcd.print("*");
        password[pozisyon] = whichKey;
        pozisyon++;
      }
      if (pozisyon == 4) {
        // Verificare parola corecta
        if(strcmp(password, "1234") == 0) {
          Serial.println("Am trecut de asta");
          digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(5, 0);
          lcd.print("Sistem dezarmat");
          Serial.println("Am facut asta");
          delay(3000);
          isArmed = false;
          lcd.clear();
          break;
        } 
        else {
          // Verificare parola incorecta
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
          lcd.print("Parola Incorecta!");
          delay(1000);
          lcd.clear();
          pozisyon = 0;
          attempts++;
          if(attempts == 3)
          {
             lcd.clear();
             break;
          }
        }
      } 
    } while (isArmed);
 }
}


// Senzor PIR
void pirsenzor() {
   distsenzor();
   val = digitalRead(pir);  // read input value
  if (val == HIGH && !isArmed && distance <= 250) {      
     digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, HIGH);
    delay(300);
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW);  // turn LED ON
    if (pirState == LOW) {
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("Motion detected at");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(distance);
      lcd.print(" m ");
      pirState = HIGH;
    }
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin4, LOW); // turn LED OFF
    if (pirState == HIGH) {
      lcd.clear();
      pirState = LOW;
    }
  }
}
//Senzor distanta
void distsenzor() { 
  digitalWrite(trigerPin, LOW);  // ensure trigger is low
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigerPin, HIGH); // send a 10us high to trigger
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigerPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH); //Measure the duration of the echo pulse
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;  //Calculate the distance using the speed of sound
  if (distance >= 400 || distance <= 2) {  //Check if the distance is out of range
  }
}
```

Everything is good I push the button to arm the system, the system ask to introduce the password everything is ok but when disarm function is called the function bypass password verification step.

A mention I have a pushbutton with a double function (arm/disarm system).

Sorry for my bad english :).

a suggestion or a solution please.

Comment: Also this Serial.println("Am facut asta"); is just for debug and see the code go directly to Sistem dezarmat

Comment: In the do loop you should start with pozison = 0. It's probably still set to 4 from previous arm() call.

Answer (score 1):

When you arm the system with

```
isArmed = true;
```

you should also reset

```
pozisyon = 0;
```

because `pozisyon == 4` is used as an indicator that a password has been entered